# Cauchy's sequence in sup-form

Tags: sequences-and-series, continuity, cauchy-sequences

How to prove the below theorem ?

> Prove that the sequence $f_1$, $f_2$,... converges uniformly to a continuous function, $f\colon [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, by showing that it is a Cauchy sequence in the sup-norm.

Comment: how is defined $f_n$ ?

Comment: I suspect @mike111 wants to prove that the space of continuous functions is complete...

Comment: The question isn't very clear as asked. What are the assumptions on the sequence $f_n$?